# Tkinter Import Syntax Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am getting an error whenever I try to import the tkinter module. I'm using Python 3.4 so the capital T isn't an issue.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

It throws back an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3372
  t        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be somehow existing in the init file itself. Just go to the file in your pc.

```
C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py
```

Edit that **init**.py with Idle or whatever IDE you use. Next go to the line number 3372 and remove that unwanted character 't' from the line

```
 t        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
```

It'll do the work for you.

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thanks a lot! Say, with Tkinter, can we put text inside a frame?

Comment: @Sourashis Bhowmik give credit for answering your question if jay successfully solved the problem. In regard to your frame/text question, what do you mean? You can put a label, entry, or combo-box object with text inside.